# AttributeError: 'AsyncEngine' object has no attribute '_run_ddl_visitor'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm rewriting my code in asyncio, so I'm shifting to asynchronous API of SQLAlchemy, but I'm getting this error which i couldn't figure out, I've tried searching for 2 hours but still no luck.

```
Users.__table__.create(checkfirst=True)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 959, in create
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst)
AttributeError: 'AsyncEngine' object has no attribute '_run_ddl_visitor'
```

Here's how code looks like

1. init.py of my database directory, here i define session and declarative base.

```py
import asyncio                                                                   
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

from acutebot import DB_URI


def _build_async_db_uri(uri):
    if "+asyncpg" not in uri:
        return '+asyncpg:'.join(uri.split(":", 1))
    return uri

async def start() -> declarative_base:
    engine = create_async_engine(_build_async_db_uri(DB_URI))
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        BASE.metadata.bind = engine
        await conn.run_sync(BASE.metadata.create_all)
    return scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False, class_=Asyn>


BASE = declarative_base()
SESSION = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start())
```

2. Users table file.

```py
class Users(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    user_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    fullname = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False)
    username = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, user_id: str, fullname: str, username: str = None):
        self.user_id = str(user_id)
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.username = username

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User {} ({})>".format(self.username, self.user_id)

Users.__table__.create(checkfirst=True)
```

Comment: If your table gets created by `Base.metadata.create_all` you don't need the synchronous call to `Table.create` in the users file.